# PHP Pixel Map Group Efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, coordinates

I currently have a map that is 1600 x 1600 stored in MySQL(2,560,000 records).  I'm rendering a simple 25x25 map out to users for interaction.  Users can "claim" tiles on this map.  I'd like to be able to calculate the number of open faces for tiles owned by a given user.  I can divide this out by the total tiles owned to determine an arbitrary efficientcy rating.

All map coordinates are simply stored as X/Y values.

I'm looking for something that can potentially process an array of said X/Y values and determine how many open faces are accessible for each owned group.  For example...

```
0 = player
x x x x x
x x 0 x x
x x x x x
4 open faces

x x x x x 
x x 0 x x 
x x 0 x x 
x x x x x 
6 open faces

x x x x x 
x x x 0 x
x x 0 x x
x x x x x 
8 open faces
```

Right now I'm doing some inefficient array looping to calculate this out.  I have a simple counter, then I'm looping through an array of all values and am looking for values +-1 in each direction of X and Y to reduce the count.  Each loop either adds 0-4 to the total counter based on the number of finds.  The inherent problem with this method is that as a group grows, it will take longer and longer to calculate out.  Since it's possible for one group to consume 20,000 points o rmore, it's quite a burden.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would have expected your third example to be 6 open faces again, because 2 of those faces are "shared"

Comment: That's what makes this a unique problem.  It's different from what you'd normally think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final block of simple code I came up with to determine the geo efficiency.  Some names of things have been changed. :P

I'm running with notices on, and everything's ajax, so I decided to go with single isset checks on a multi-dimensional instead of something else.

```
$sql = 'SELECT map_x, map_y FROM Map WHERE person_id = :person_id';
$query = $DB->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':nation_id' => $this->person_id));
$counter = 0;
$coords = array();
while($row = $query->fetch())
{
    ++$counter;
    $coords[$row['map_x']][$row['map_y']] = 1;
}
$faces = 0;
foreach($coords as $x => $batch)
{
    foreach($batch as $y => $junk)
    {
        $hits = 4;
        if(isset($coords[$x + 1][$y]))
        {
            --$hits;
        }
        if(isset($coords[$x - 1][$y]))
        {
            --$hits;
        }
        if(isset($coords[$x][$y - 1]))
        {
            --$hits;
        }
        if(isset($coords[$x][$y + 1]))
        {
            --$hits;
        }
        $faces += $hits;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know instead of using the hits variable, I could easily increment the faces variable, but there's a few extra features that were added that come after the ifs.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would involve creating a `Point` class. For example:

```
class Point {
    public $x;
    public $y;

    public function __construct($x, $y){
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function getNeighbors(){
        // TODO: What if we are at the edge of the board?

        return array(
            new Point($x+1, $y+1),
            new Point($x+1, $y-1),
            new Point($x-1, $y+1),
            new Point($x-1, $y-1),
        );
    }
}
```

Create instances from that class for each point occupied by a user:

```
// Generate array of Points from database
$user_points = array(new Point(134, 245), new Point(146, 456));
```

Iterate through to generate all the neighbors:

```
// Get a flat array of neighbor Points
$neighbors = array_merge(array_map(function($point){
    return $point->getNeighbors();
}, $user_points));

// TOOD: Remove Points that are equal to values in $user_points
```

Then, lastly, submit a `COUNT` query for the "neighbor" points to determine how many are occupied by other users and remove those from the total.

(Note: I've added TODOs where more work is to be done.)

---

> The inherent problem with this method is that as a group grows, it will take longer and longer to calculate out.

You should consider using an in-memory key-value store, like [Redis](http://redis.io). But yes, the look-up time (for occupied blocks), in time complexity, appears linear with regard to the number of entries.

Comment: When knocking out points, how would I determine if 2 tiles share the same open tile to count it as multiple faces?  I'll give anything a shot to see if I can make it faster.  I'll post my current solution tomorrow.  Thanks for the idea Jacob!